# How to find specific node in the array of nested objects using the object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of nested objects, and I need to compare values with a flat array and update the **matchFound** property.

If **matchFound** is true for parents, all children **matchFound** should be true.

```js
treeData = [{
    field: 'make',
    name: 'Infiniti',
    matchFound: null,
    children: [{
        field: 'model',
        name: 'G50',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Luxe',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        field: 'model',
        name: 'QX50',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            matchFound: null
          },
          {
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Luxe',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    field: 'make',
    name: 'BMW',
    matchFound: null,
    children: [{
        field: 'model',
        name: '2 Series',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Coupé',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Gran Coupé',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        field: 'model',
        name: '3 Series',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'Sedan',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            field: 'trim',
            name: 'PHEV',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is the flatData array whose object I need to use to find respective node in the tree data and update the property.
for e.g. { make: "BMW" } - It should update
{field: 'make',
name: 'BMW',
matchFound: true,...}, and all its children.

{
make: "Infiniti",
model: "G50",
trim: "Luxe"
} should only update **matchFound** of Luxe.

My biggest challenge is finding the correct node in the treeData using flatData. If changing the data structure of flatData helps I can do that as well.

```js
   flatData = [{
      make: "Infiniti",
      model: "G50",
      trim: "Luxe"
    }, {
      make: "Infiniti",
      model: "G50",
      trim: "Pure AWD"
    }, {
      make: "BMW"
    }]
```

I converted flflatData into treeData structure, but couldn't make use of it.

```js
[{
        field: 'make',
        name: 'Infiniti',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            field: 'model',
            name: 'G50',
            matchFound: null,
            children: [{
                field: 'trim',
                name: 'Pure AWD',
                matchFound: true,
              },
              {
                field: 'trim',
                name: 'Luxe',
                matchFound: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        field: 'make',
        name: 'BMW',
        matchFound: true
      },
    ];
```

My attempt which is nowhere near the solution as I am not able to the find the right node in the treeData.

```js
for (const item of this.flatData) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeData.length; i++) {
      if (this.treeData[i].name === `${value}`) {
        this.treeData[i].matchFound = true;
        if (this.treeData[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
          this.updateAllChildren(i, this.treeData[i].children);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Set matchFound true for all the children
  function updateAllChildren(index, items) {
    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      this.treeData[index].children[j].matchFound = true;
      if (this.treeData[index].children[j].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        for (let k = 0; k < this.treeData[index].children[j].children.length; k++) {
            this.treeData[index].children[j].children[k].matchFound = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-urdmjl?file=PathFinder.js)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the number of object keys as number of levels you need to travel?
For example  for `{ make: "BMW" }` you have one key and then you can go on the first level and search for the object that has `name === 'BMW'`.

For `{ make: "Infiniti", model: "G50", trim: "Luxe" }` you need to go 3 levels the first level is where `name` equals `"Infiniti"`, then in that object you go one level down and search for `name` equal `"G50"`, once you find that object you go one more level and search for the object that match `name` equal `"Luxe"`.
That's for finding your target. Then, for that object and it's children you se `matchFound` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, the number of the object keys will always correctly reflect the levels.